# Google Apps Script in Sheets to remove last character

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to remove the last character of each row in a specific column, and unfortunately could not find any ways as to accomplish this.

Sample data looks as follows:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function removeLastCharacter() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  const rng = sh.getRange('A2:A' + sh.getLastRow())
  const data = rng.getValues()
  data.map(r => r[0] = r[0].substring(0, r[0].length - 1))
  rng.setValues(data)
}
```

or if you want to remove `:`

```
function removeLastCharacter() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  const rng = sh.getRange('A2:A' + sh.getLastRow())
  const data = rng.getValues()
  data.map(r => r[0] = r[0].replace(/:/,""))
  rng.setValues(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another direction, how about using TextFinder as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(".$").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
}
```

- In this sample script, from your showing sample image, the last character of the cells "A2:A" is removed.
- If you want to remove the specific character (`:`) at the last character, please modify `.$` to `:$`.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))